# Account vault query in corda

Tags: corda

i am running this command :
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo

and getting this error:
Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `java.lang.Class`, problem: com.r3.corda.lib.accounts.contracts.states.AccountInfo
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

Comment: Do you have `accounts-contracts` CorDapp installed on your node? i.e. do you have `accounts-contracts-1.0.jar` file inside the `cordapps` folder of your node?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this account sample for your question. As Adel points out in the comment, you will need https://github.com/corda/accounts-demo-supplychain/blob/master/contracts/build.gradle#L38 in you contract level build.gradle.

Alternatively, You can also query your accounts inside a flow.